# MYSQL UNIQUE for date part of a date field

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique

I have the field `sync_date` (type DATETIME) in my table `visit`. I would like that `sync_date` can not repeat in the same day. So, I have the idea to have `sync_date` as an UNIQUE field. But it doesn't work for this case because I don't want it takes into account the hour part.

**For example**

> today I can have this: 
>       `sync_date` = '2013-05-14 08:45:00' 
>  So today MySQL shouldn't admit the same 
>       '2013-05-14'    anymore but tomorrow it does can happens.

Comment: you are passing datetime on date field. what are you actually trying to achieve

Comment: You cannot be storing data of the form '2013-05-14 08:45:00' is a `DATE` field. I can only assume that the field is a either a `datetime` or a `timestamp`. If you change the datatype to be a `date` then you will be able to enforce a unique constraint

Comment: Excuse me, I have corrected it. What I want is to put a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT by day. I don't want that data repeats during the day. How can I do that?

Comment: You could add a separate field that contains just the DATE and have a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on that.  Otherwise I think you will have to create a trigger, or check in the code before adding a new record.

Comment: My problem is that I cannot modify the database. I have that validation in the code but for any reason I continue getting duplicate data in some cases. I have thought about use a trigger in order to validate the input data before it is inserted, but I don't know how can I do that. I know something about triggers but, I don't know how a trigger can avoid insertion if the data doesn't meet my rules. Your sugestion has been very important for me. Thanks.